# Stability of Euler-Cromer method

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, computational-physics, differential-equations, stability

Euler method doesn't perform well in the context of oscillatory problems like the harmonic oscillator; the amplitude of the oscillation gets bigger with time, which clearly contradicts theory as no energy is being added into the system.

For instance, consider a simple pendulum of length $l$ and mass $m$. It can be proven that given the following difference equations

\begin{cases}
 \omega_{i+1} = \omega_{i}-\frac{g}{l}\theta_i \Delta t \\
 \theta_{i+1} = \theta_i+\omega_i\Delta t
\end{cases}

where $\theta$ is the angle, $\omega = \dot{\theta}$ the angular velocity and $\Delta t$ the time-step, the mechanical energy of the system is

\begin{equation}
 E_{i+1} = E_{i} + \frac{1}{2}mgl(\omega_i^2+\frac{g}{l} \theta_i^2) \Delta t^2
\end{equation}

The energy increases at every iteration, since the second term is strictly positive. Therefore, my textbook (Giordano-Hisao) suggests to use Euler-Cromer method, slightly modifying the previous system

\begin{cases}
 \omega_{i+1} = \omega_{i}-\frac{g}{l}\theta_i \Delta t \\
 \theta_{i+1} = \theta_i+\omega_{i+1}\Delta t
\end{cases}

This algorithm does work better, as not only the amplitude of the oscillation is constant, but also the energy no longer blows up. Numerically simulating the system above[image]

In the figure we see that energy is periodic, but is there a way to prove that *a priori*? Will this method always be stable for oscillatory problems? Also, what's the period of the energy? Is it the same as the period of the system?

Answer (score 1):

The figure is not proof of periodicity. It only indicates that a possible variation of the energy is small or, in another way, it could be visible only over times much longer than the almost ten periods shown in the figure.

Such a nice behavior, as compared with the explicit Euler method, could be anticipated by the symplectic nature of the Euler-Cromer method. Symplectic methods preserve the [symplectic structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_manifold) of the phase space of Hamiltonian systems. This is a property with deep consequences.
The most important for the present questions is that a symplectic method provides an approximate integration of the Hamiltonian of interest (say $H$) but, for every choice of the time steep ($\Delta t$), provides an *exact* integration of a different Hamiltonian, say $H'(\Delta t)$. Differences between $H$ and $H'$ go to zero, generally with the same power of the time step as the global error of the method.

Maintaining the Hamiltonian character of the evolution allows using the [KAM theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Arnold%E2%80%93Moser_theorem#KAM_theory) to ensure the topological stability of the slightly perturbed motion.

Moreover, long-time behavior can also be controlled theoretically by using asymptotic results for Hamiltonian systems. In particular, [Nekhoroshev estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nekhoroshev_estimates) allows us to predict that numerical and theoretical evolutions will remain close for times exponentially increasing with decreasing $\Delta t$.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I don't have access to Cromer 1981 paper in which his results are shown, but I guess the one you described could be a possible way to prove stability.